# iOS Memory Effiency and Performance: Pass Data via Segue or Create New Instance?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to understand why one option would be better than the other in terms of memory efficiency and performance.

Currently I have 3 `UIViewController` classes and an `NSObject` class.

The flow is `ViewControllerOne` -> `ViewControllerTwo` -> `ViewControllerThree`. The `NSObject` instance is only used in `ViewControllerOne` and `ViewControllerThree`.

For simplicity the classes are defined something like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        print("SUPER INIT")
    }
}

class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController
{
    var myClass = MyClass()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "ViewControllerTwoSegue"
        {
            if let viewControllerTwo = segue.destination as? ViewControllerTwo
            {
                viewControllerTwo.myClass = myClass
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController
{
    // Not being used
    var myClass: MyClass?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "ViewControllerThreeSegue"
        {
            if let viewControllerThree = segue.destination as? ViewControllerThree
            {
                viewControllerThree.myClass = myClass
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewControllerThree: UIViewController
{
    // Being used
    var myClass: MyClass?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

    }
}
```

Currently in my app, I am passing a reference to the instance of `MyClass` contained in `ViewControllerOne` to `ViewControllerThree` via the middle man `ViewControllerTwo`.

In terms of memory management and efficiency, I don't see much of a difference versus if I were to create a **new** instance of `MyClass` in `ViewControllerThree` and removing the unused instance in `ViewControllerTwo` even though it creates two instances of `MyClass`:

```
class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController
{
    // Not being used
//        var myClass: MyClass?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "ViewControllerThreeSegue"
        {
            if let viewControllerThree = segue.destination as? ViewControllerThree
            {
//                    viewControllerThree.myClass = myClass
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewControllerThree: UIViewController
{
    // Being used
    var myClass = MyClass()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to follow proper coding standards and would like to know if I should favor one or the other to ensure my app is optimized to operate at its best?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to follow proper coding standards and would like to know if I
>   should favor one or the other to ensure my app is optimized to operate
>   at its best?

There is no standards applying here really, I believe the decision should be purely functional.

- Where do you acquire the data that will be held by the instances of MyClass?
- In which controller do you need it (seems like the 3rd)?
- If you go back from your 3rd controller to the 2nd and back again, do you need the data to be consistent?
- Is there another entry point than the 1st controller? (such as deep links)
- etc

There is a slight difference in processing and memory usage favouring your initial implementation (1 alloc & init vs possibly multiple alloc/init/dealloc) but it is of no consequence and should not affect the way you design/implement your application.

Comment: the data does not need to be consistent....I was only concerned about multiple alloc/init if multiple classes each create an instance of `MyClass` versus just creating one instance at the top level and passing its reference to the child classes...would this not make much difference?

Answer (score 0):

There is *no significant difference* whatever between your two proposed courses of action. To see why, you have to know what a storyboard is.

A storyboard is a source of instances; making view controller instances is what it does. Asking a storyboard, explicit or implicitly, for a view controller, is merely another way of instantiating that view controller class.

There is thus *no significant difference* between saying `ViewControllerThree()`, and saying "Hey there, storyboard, please hand me a ViewControllerThree instance" — which is what triggering a segue *does* say.

You might have a mental picture that the storyboard is chock full of view controllers, so merely having or loading a storyboard would somehow bring all those view controller into existence at once. But that is not true. A storyboard is chock full of *nibs* — one view controller nib and one view nib, per scene — and *none* of those nibs is even loaded until it is actively needed.

So, the reason for preferring a storyboard over pure code would simply be the convenience of designing everything (views and their configuration, segues, etc.) in a storyboard. This can clarify your code considerably (though it does not necessarily make for *less* code). The reason for preferring code over a storyboard would be, say, that you don't like the indirect nature `prepare(for:sender:)` — you want to instantiate and configure the next view controller yourself, all in one move.

My own apps are about fifty-fifty between using a storyboard and not using one. But in no case does the choice have *anything* to do with "in terms of memory efficiency and performance."

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so to sum it up, you're basically saying no difference between passing an instance of `MyClass` created in `ViewControllerOne` to `ViewControllerThree` versus creating a `new` instance of `MyClass` in `ViewControllerThree`?